# Disable "Share" option in Yammer Open Graph object

Tags: php, share, yammer

Using the Yammer REST API I can include Open Graph (og) elements that will cause a graphic block to appear at the bottom of my generated post in Yammer:

```
$data = array(
    'title' => $title,
    'body' => $body,
    'group_id' => $yammer_group_id,
    'og_url' => $url_for_this_item,
    'og_title' => $title,
    'og_site_name' => 'Title of Our Site'
);

$json = json_encode($data);
$result = post_yammer($yammer_token, 'messages.json', $json);
```

When the graphic block is hovered over in Yammer, a strip of links appears at the bottom, one of which is "Share".

Is there any way to disable this functionality per-post (or overall for that matter) in Yammer - either the "Share" link specifically or the whole strip of links? My client has certain posts they'd like to make but discourage sharing.

I am guessing the answer is "no" - it's a pretty specific request and unlikely to be a common one - but figure someone might have an insight.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to disable the links including Share from appearing in the Yammer user interface.